# Access Root UINavigationController from Pushed UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I've run into a problem with my Project.

Every time I try to access my UINavigationController from a Pushed UIViewController, I get "(null)" as a return.

So this is my project is structured:

```
1. AppDelegate.m initalises UINavigation Controller
2. UINavigation Controller starts with Welcome Page
3. Welcome Page Pushes New UIViewController on Button Press
4. UIViewController returns (null) when self.navigationController called
```

OK, so here's some code, in my Welcome Page I'm calling this:

```
MyClass *theChatRoom = [[MyClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChatRoom" bundle:nil];
[theChatRoom setTitle:[unitCode text]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:theChatRoom animated:YES];
```

Which works fine, it pushes the new View Controller.

But then in MyClass.m :

```
@implementation MyClass

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.navigationController]);
    }
    return self;
}
```

This returns (null)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the documentation, the `navigationController` of `UIViewController`:

> This property is nil if the view controller is not embedded inside a
>   navigation controller.

That's said, if you access the `navigationController` before embedding into the `UINavigationController`(not push yet), it will return nil. So you can access it in the `viewDidLoad` but no in `- (id)initWithNibName:bundle:`.

Comment: Good answer. However I'm trying to do this `UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
[[[self navigationController] navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem: backButton];` and cannot get it to work.
What gives?

Comment: Nevermind, found that you have to set the Back button in the parent view controller, and not in the View Controller itself.

Comment: Just did this in a really complex project and for what it's worth it did not assign to non nil on viewDidLoad. Could be some ugly hack lower in the project that I'm on though. Will try this in a clean project.